# angularJS: ui-router $state.go only works on first click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to learn how to use AngularJS and I stumbled upon a problem I can't solve...

The code below should:
- show 2 views: 1 to show some names ("receivers") on the left and one to show the main content (an intro or a list for the corresponding person ("currentReceiver"))
- navigate via $state.go to the corresponding "wishlist" and changing the URL to ".../#/wishlist/"

The code I have seems to work only when I click on a name the first time... Once I've clicked once, the url stays empty ('.../#/') and the intro page is shown...

Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong or where I should look to debug this problem...?

**Part of my index.html**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" ui-view="wishlists">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-20 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" ui-view="wishes">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    ...     

</body>
```

**wishlist.tmpl.html**
(template of view 'wishlist' on left hand side wish link to functon "setCurrentReceiver")

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-repeat="receiver in receivers" ng-class="{'active': isCurrentReceiver(receiver)}">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentReceiver(receiver)">{{receiver.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**gimmi-app.js**
(with $state.go in function setCurrentReceiver)

```
angular.module('Gimmi', [
    'ui.router',
    'wishlist',
    'wishlist.wish',
    'wishlist.receiver'
])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('gimmi', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true
        })
    ;
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    //--------------------------------------------------
    // RECEIVER MODULE
    //--------------------------------------------------

    $scope.receivers = [
        {"id": 1, "name": "XXX", "age": 31, "gender": "m"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "YYY", "age": 28, "gender": "v"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "ZZZ", "age": 59, "gender": "v"},
    ];

    $scope.currentReceiver = null;

    function setCurrentReceiver(receiver) {
        $scope.currentReceiver = receiver;

        $state.go('gimmi.wishlist.wish', {receiverName: receiver.name});

        cancelEditing();
        cancelCreating();
    }

    function isCurrentReceiver(receiver) {
        return $scope.currentReceiver !== null && receiver.id === $scope.currentReceiver.id;
    }

    $scope.setCurrentReceiver = setCurrentReceiver;
    $scope.isCurrentReceiver = isCurrentReceiver;

    //--------------------------------------------------
    // WISHLIST MODULE
    //--------------------------------------------------

    $scope.wishes = [

        {"id": 1, "title": "Smartphone", "price": 250, "status": "reserved", "receiverID": 1},
        {"id": 2, "title": "Lamzac", "price": 75, "status": "free", "receiverID": 1},
        {"id": 3, "title": "Fatboy", "price": 140, "status": "free", "receiverID": 1},
        {"id": 4, "title": "Pioneer DJM 800", "price": 800, "status": "reserved", "receiverID": 1},
        {"id": 5, "title": "Snowboard", "price": 500, "status": "free", "receiverID": 2}

    ];
```

**wishlist.js** 
(with the view to show the left hand side and the intro page when url = '/')

```
angular.module('wishlist', [
    'gimmi.models.wishlist'
])
    .config(function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('gimmi.wishlist', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    'wishlists@': {
                        controller: 'wishlistCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'app/wishlist/wishlist.tmpl.html'
                    }
                    ,'wishes@': {
                        controller: 'wishCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'app/wishlist/intro.tmpl.html'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;
    })

    .controller('wishlistCtrl', function wishlistCtrl($scope){

    });
});
```

**wish.js**
(the .js with the state to which I refer in $state.go)

```
angular.module('wishlist.wish', [
    'gimmi.models.wishlist',
    'gimmi.models.wish',
    'wishlist.wish.create',
    'wishlist.wish.edit'    
])
    .config(function($stateProvider){

        $stateProvider
            .state('gimmi.wishlist.wish', {
                url: 'wishlist/:receiverName',
                views: {
                    'wishes@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/wishlist/wish/wish.tmpl.html',
                        controller:'wishCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;
    })

    .controller('wishCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.currentReceiverName = $stateParams.receiverName;
    })

;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the `href="#"` from the link.

Explanation: `ng-click` is bound to the `onclick` JavaScript event. Unless you `return false` or do `event.preventDefault()` the default behavior of the click will be executed and this is open the url defined in the `href` attribute.

Comment: So simple... :) But can you explain why this wasn't working with the href="#"? 
If I understand the $stateProvider: going to a state with $state.go will change the URL with the url in the state. Why isn't this working with href="#"?

Comment: `ng-click` should be bound to the `onclick` event and it is triggered before the actual link. Unless you return false in the `onclick` event, the actual link will be called. In your case after `setCurrentReceiver(receiver)` is executed the browser will navigate to the link target and this is `#`because of `href="#"`

Comment: I had the same issue on my project, but I only started getting the side-effect of bouncing back to home page this year. Strange... I'm guessing it must have been a Chrome update.